# Python: why partition(sep) is faster than split(sep, maxsplit=1)

Tags: python, string, algorithm, performance, cpython

I found an interesting thing that `partition` is faster than `split` when get whole substring after the separator. I have tested in Python 3.5 and 3.6 (Cpython)

```
In [1]: s = 'validate_field_name'

In [2]: s.partition('_')[-1]
Out[2]: 'field_name'

In [3]: s.split('_', maxsplit=1)[-1]
Out[3]: 'field_name'

In [4]: %timeit s.partition('_')[-1]
220 ns ± 1.12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit s.split('_', maxsplit=1)[-1]
745 ns ± 48.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit s[s.find('_')+1:]
340 ns ± 1.44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

I look through the Cpython source code and found the `partition` use the `FASTSEARCH` algorithm, see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/stringlib/partition.h#L25). And the `split` only use `FASTSEARCH` when the separator string's length is larger than 1, see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L157). But I have tested on sep string which length is larger. I got same result.

I guess the reason is `partition` return a three elements tuple, instead of a list.

I want to know more details.

Comment: Yes, part of the reason is that building a fixed length tuple is more efficient than building an arbitrary length list.

Comment: You are also calling `split` with a keyword argument, i.e. `s.split('_', maxsplit=1)` instead of a simple `s.split('_', 1)`.

Answer (score 6):

Microbenchmarks can be misleading

```
py -m timeit "'validate_field_name'.split('_', maxsplit=1)[-1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.568 usec per loop

py -m timeit "'validate_field_name'.split('_', 1)[-1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.317 usec per loop
```

Just passing the argument as positional or keyword changes the time significantly. So I would guess another reason partition is faster, because it does not need a second argument...

Comment: It's amazing. I agree with what you said, but I test a simple function that do nothing and got following result.

    In [16]: def func(a, b):
        ...:     pass
        ...: 

    In [17]: %timeit func(1, 2)
    95.8 ns ± 1.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

    In [18]: %timeit func(1, b=2)
    123 ns ± 2.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

The difference is not obvious. I think the builtin fucntion is special. It take some other optimization.